# How can I get data from the url and parse it for getting hobbies or names?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I tried so many things and I researched lots of sites. But I can't find that how to parse this data without using modules. I am using node.js for this. My problem is I can't get the data from url to parse it. I hope my question is clear now. Thanks for answers.

```
const https = require("https");

https.get("https://coderbyte.com/api/challenges/json/rest-get-simple", (resp) => {
    
  }
);
```

Comment: [`resp` is an object](https://coderbyte.com/api/challenges/json/rest-get-simple). What is your expected output?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Emre have a look at https://nodejs.org/api/https.html#https_https_get_options_callback There you see an example. I also updated my question in that regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation of the https.get function](https://nodejs.org/api/https.html#https_https_get_options_callback) provides you with an example. Does that help you?

```
const https = require('https');

https.get("https://coderbyte.com/api/challenges/json/rest-get-simple", (res) => {
  res.on('data', (d) => {
    obj = JSON.parse(d.toString());
    console.log("Hobbies",obj.hobbies);
  });

}).on('error', (e) => {
  console.error(e);
});
```

So within the get callback you need a listener on if some data was received.

Comment: sorry for this. I updated the question. I hope its clear now. Thank you.